# Multiple patterns search in Regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omXve.png)

```
import re
pattern=r'\d+'
pattern1= r'\d+\s'
place = re.search((pattern | pattern1),s)
```

I need this regex to work for s='2m' as well as s='2 m' so that I can find m and separate it also it should for in case of s='2 mins' or s= '2mins'

can someone please help me with this. Also PFA
Thanks

Comment: Try `re.search("|".join([pattern, pattern1]), s)`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single pattern with an alternation:

```
\b\d+\s*(?:m|mins)\b
```

Sample script:

```
inp = 'I saw it 2 mins ago'
if (re.search(r'\b\d+\s*(?:m|mins)\b', inp)):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: I apologize for the DV. It was a mistake as I was going to UV, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern that does not use alternation but rather optional sub-expressions:

```
\b\d+ ?m(?:ins)?\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUPZox/1/)

1. `\b` Asserts position at a word boundary.
2. `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.
3. `?` Optional space. If you want to allow multiple spaces, then use  `*`.
4. `m` Matches 'm'.
5. `(?:ins)?` Matches optional 'ins' in a non-capturing group.
6. `\b` Asserts position at a word boundary.

Use:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'\b\d+ ?m(?:ins)?\b', 'See you in 2 mins or sooner')
if m:
    print(m[0])
```

Prints:

```
2 mins
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/Z0Rarh)